Estimate of mean in semiparametric model. Box-Cox fails for negative mean
I have a time series of positive values $X_t \geq 0$ satisfying the following model:
$$\begin{cases}f_*(X_{t}) = f_*(X_{t-1}) + \mu + \varepsilon_{t}, &\forall t \in \{1,2,\dots,T\},\\
X_0 = 1, &\textit{a.s.}
\end{cases}$$
with $\{X_{t}\}_{t=0}^T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+, X_0 = 1$, and $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t=1}^T$ $\textit{i.i.d}$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
I don't know $f_*$ a priori, but I know that it satisfies:
$$f^* \in \mathcal{F} \subseteq \{f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R} \mid f(1)=0, f'(1)=1, f'(x)>0\},$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is a dictionary of functions. Let's assume that $f_* \in \mathcal{F}$. My goal is to estimate $\mu$.
For a given function $f \in \mathcal{F}$, I can get estimates $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ by taking the sample average and variance of $\{f(X_{t}) - f(X_{t-1})\}_{t=1}^T$.
The question then is: How can I choose the "best" function $f \in \mathcal{F}$ to estimate $\mu$?

What I have tried already:
I tried exploring a solution with some simulated data (assuming Gaussian errors), with $f_* = \log$ versus $f(x) = x-1$.

My first idea was to use a Box-Cox like procedure to choose the best function from the set $\mathcal{F}$. I would simply choose the function that maximizes the likelihood of joint error distribution:

$$\mathcal{L}(\hat{\varepsilon}^f) := \prod_{t=1}^T\phi_{\hat{\sigma}}(\hat{\varepsilon}^f_{t})\dot{f}(x_{t}),$$
where:
$$\hat{\varepsilon}^f_{t} := f(X_{t}) - f(X_{t-1}) - \hat{\mu} ,\qquad t \in \{1,2,\dots,T\},$$
$\phi_{\hat{\sigma}}$ is the density of a distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$, and $\dot{f}(y)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $y$.
This works very well when $\mu>0$. The problem happens when $\mu<0$. In that case, the series $X_t$ decreases rapidly to zero, and we observe that $x-1$ has a much higher likelihood, despite the clear trend in the behavior of the residuals.
I think the problem is that when $\mu$ is negative, the series $X_t$ decreases rapidly to zero, and the residuals are very small in magnitude when we use $f(x) = x-1$. This makes the likelihood of the residuals very high, even though the residuals are evidently not normally distributed for small $t.$ I remember seeing another question in this site that mentioned that the Box-Cox transformation is sensitive to the scale of the data.

My second idea was to use the procedure 1) above, but changing the estimation to be:
$$f(X_t)/\sqrt{t} = \sqrt{t}\mu + u_t,$$
where $u_t$ are errors with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Note that the residuals are not independent in this case.

In that case I would just plug in $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ (defined above) in the likelihood function assuming that the errors are normally distributed and independent (which is not true, naturally). I would then choose from $\mathcal{F}$ the function that maximizes the likelihood of the residuals in this case.
With this procedure, I was able to correctly identify the function $f_*(x) = \log(x)$ as the best function to estimate $\mu$ with both positive and negative signs. However, I am not sure if this is the best way to proceed, since it is not clear to me if it makes sense to assume that the residuals are independent in this case.

I know that there are other (nonparametric) methods to transform both sides of a regression equation, such as AVAS. But it would not be clear to me how to apply this method in this case when the transformation is the same on both sides of the equation, and there is the linear term $\mu$.

What I am looking for: Some guidance on how to proceed in this case. I am not sure if the procedure 2) is the best way to proceed (even though it seems to work). I am also not sure if there is a better way to proceed in this case. I would appreciate any help on this matter.
